# MVC - Cannot resolve view (controllers and views in separate projects)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have a Solution with 4 projects:

- `AS.Core.Common` (references: Data, Web)
- `AS.Core.Controllers` (references: Common, Data, Web)
- `AS.Core.Data`
- `AS.Core.Web` (references: Data)

In my controllers, anywhere that I return a view:

> return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");

It is highlighted in red and I get a `"Cannot resolve view '~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml'"`.

All four projects build successfully but when I hit F5 I get the following:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

How can I get my controllers to see my views so they resolve properly? I'm assuming this is why I get the 404 response.

My `Global.asax.cs` look like so:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // Register the default hubs route: ~/signalr
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

My `RouteConfig.cs` (I added namespaces but it appears to have not helped)

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        namespaces: new[] { "AS.Core.Controllers" },
        defaults: new 
        {
            controller = "Home", 
            action = "Index", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        });
}
```

This is my `HomeController.cs`

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
        return View();
    }
 }
```

Comment: The problem is probably NOT about finding the view. Not finding the view would render an other more specific error, not a 404. Your error is probably related to the routing. How's the routing table in global.asax?

Comment: I added my routing to my original post.

Comment: Sorry not clear enough :) whats in the RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes) method.

Comment: I guess you do not have a HomeController.cs containing a class named HomeController with a method named Index()   ??

Comment: I do have a HomeController.cs with an Index method in it. I've added that to the original post as well.

Comment: Just saw (in other comment) that your controllers is in an other project, right? Then you probably should add *namespaces: new string[]{"YourControllerProjsNameSpace"}* into your MapRoute() .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) you could return a valid View in the respective controller's views's folder. For sample, if you have a controller called Product, you could have a folder in the path `~/Views/Product/Index.cshtml`. In your `Index` action, you just return a View using the `View()` method of the `Controller` class base that all controllers in asp.net mvc should inherits. For sample:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

Asp.Net will find a View on the folder with the same name of your Action, `Index` in this case.

You also could return another View using the `View` method since you have the respective View on the folder, for sample:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View("About");
}
```

Considering this case, you should have a View named `About` in the `Product` folder. For sample: `~/Views/Product/About.cshtml`.

If you change your controllers to another project (class library), you have to set on the asp.net mvc initialization what is the default namespace of your controllers, try something like this on the `Global.asax` file and `Application_Start` method:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("NamespaceOfYourProject.Controllers");
```

Take a look at this article: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/storing-asp-net-mvc-controllers-views-in-separate-assemblies.aspx

Comment: I do have a folder of "/Views/Home" with an 'Index.cshtml' in it. For some reason it's not resolving it.

Comment: how about the routing? did you change something?

Comment: I did not and perhaps that's my problem? Originally I had my controllers in my Web project but I deleted the directory and created a new project for my Controllers. I'll update my original post with my routes.

Comment: Look my edits, maybe that's the reason! Asp.Net MVC is not finding the right controller.